# I can't clone gitlab repo from siteground ssh session

Tags: git, gitlab

I created a new project directly in GitLab. On my Mac, I did a clone, and found that it communicates with gitlab. I ssh'd onto my account on SIteground and tried to clone there as well. I got:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Wrong port? Some speecial extra step required? Tech support at SiteGround unhelpfully gave me instructions for git HUB, not git LAB. Making the obvious substitution in those instructons resulted in the same error message. They told me to create a `~/.shh/config` file containing:

```
Host us16.siteground.us
ForwardAgent yes
```

I did. No change in result.

Ideas?

Comment: GitLab is hosted somewhere internally right? Gonna put money on you're hitting a firewall.

Comment: GitLab can be hosted internally, similar to GitHub Enterprise. Most people use GitLab.com, though, which works just like GitHub.com.

Answer (score 3):

[GitLab allows connections on port `443` to work around situations like this](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/).

> All you have to do is edit your ~/.ssh/config and change the way you connect to GitLab.com. The two notable changes are Hostname and Port:

```
Host gitlab.com
    Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
    User git
    Port 443
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

SiteGround was blocking port 22 for all but whitelisted addresses, and does not list gitlab.

Comment: Did they unblock it for your specific account at your request? It seems like it's still blocked by default on most accounts.